# stopPropagation not working with nested href tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple divs listed like so:

```
<div class="msg-list clearfix" id="27705">
  <div class="thumbnail_image">
    <a href="some_path">AnchorText</a>
  </div>
  <div class="msg-date">DATA</div>
</div>
```

I've trying to catch a click event for the parent div but when clicking the href element my click event is also getting triggered instead of just following the link clicked.

Here is my jquery call:

```
//$(".msg-list a").click(function(e) {
$(".msg-list").click(function(e) {

    e.stopPropagation(); 
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".msg-list").on('click', function(e) {
    alert("div handler");
    return false;
});
$(".msg-list a").on('click', function(e) {
    alert("a handler");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/L5kC4/2

Comment: This is what is currently happening. I'm trying to ignore the click event when the anchor text is clicked and simply follow the link instead

Comment: In that case, add a handler for each element. In the `a` handler, if you don't return false you will be redirected to the href.

Comment: That did the trick...I had to call stopPropagation on (.msg-list .thumbnail_image a) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The click event, like any other event is dispatched to the elements using Bubbling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events) so any inner element clicked will trigger all the parent elements (the other way is called Tunnelling).

You have to put the stopPropagation on the anchor element onclick event or put in the element:

```
onclick="return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable the link inside the div, use this JavaScript. You have to disable Propagation on the contained element, the link!

```
$(".msg-list a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(".msg-list").on('click', function(e) {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

Comment: I thought this was your intention? Didn't you want to call the click-event on the div **unless** the link is clicked, in which case the link-targed should be followed?

Comment: Additionally, I had a small bug in my JS. In the third line, the ); was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Old question. But, I had the same problem.

Adding `e.preventDefault()` fixed the problem. The default is to follow the link. So, preventing it from following.

Also, there's no problem adding that to the `<a>` of its children.